# Float middle list item right

Tags: css, list, css-float, sass

I'm trying to float the middle list item right. So the red item with job title should apear next to the blue item. But when I float it right it puts it right of the blue one instead of left.

**So this is what I have now**

[image: So this is what I have now]

**When I float it right I get this.**

[image: When I float it right I get this.]

So how can I now correctly display it?

My SCSS

```
  .credit-list-main{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    font-size:13px;

    >li.credit-list-company{
        list-style:none;

        >h3{
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:13px;
        }

        >ul.credit-list-person{

            list-style:none;
            padding:0;
            padding-left:5px;

            >li{
                display:inline;
            }
            /*Person name*/
            >li:nth-child(1){
                background:green;
            }
            /*Job title*/
            >li:nth-child(2){
                background:red;
                float:right;
            }
            /*Person nav*/
            >li:nth-child(3){
                background:blue;
                float:right;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="credit-list-main">
                        <li class="credit-list-company">
                            <h3>Management</h3>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Cevat Yerli</li>
                                <li>CEO & President</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Avni Yerli</li>
                                <li>Managing Director</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Faruk Yerli</li>
                                <li>Managing Director</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="credit-list-company">
                            <h3>Programming Team</h3>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Filipe Amim</li>
                                <li>Game Programmer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Sandy Brand</li>
                                <li>Senior AI / Game Programmer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Dean Claassen</li>
                                <li>Senior Interface Programmer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Fernando Colomer</li>
                                <li>Senior Game Programmer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Sandy Brand</li>
                                <li>Senior AI / Game Programmer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="credit-list-company">
                            <h3>Research & Development</h3>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Christopher Balte</li>
                                <li>Software Engineer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Iva Zoltan Frey</li>
                                <li>Lead Animation Engineer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Iva Herzeg</li>
                                <li>Lead Animation Engineer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="credit-list-person">
                                <li>Christopher Balte</li>
                                <li>Software Engineer</li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: A http://www.jsfiddle.net with your code would have make this really easy for us to try and fix.

Comment: have you tried putting the person nav ahead of the job title in your scss

Comment: @otherDewi thats totally fixed it. Didn't think it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also manage like this :

```
<ul class="credit-list-person">
<li>Cevat Yerli</li>
<span>
<li>CEO & President</li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
</span>
</ul>
```

then give `float: right` to `span` and after then apply `float: left` for first li and `float: right` for second li

**Update**

Without changing the markup you could do this by setting right value as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/N2Zkp/) but better would be changing its order as answered by  @zessx

Answer (score 1):

Simply revert your two last columns :

```
<ul class="credit-list-person">
    <li>Cevat Yerli</li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a></li>
    <li>CEO & President</li>
</ul>
```